# How to create a nested UI-Bootstrap accordion?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

How to create a nested UI-Bootstrap accordion where inner and outer accordions works independent of each other.

If  one accordion group is open in outer accordion and I am doing something in inner accordion, it shouldn't affect the state of outer accordion. Below is the sample code for what I want to achieve.

> (What is happening right now is, if I open a group in inner accordion,
>   it is closing the parent outer accordion group)

```
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

  <uib-accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
    Below iss the inner accordion
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
      <uib-accordion-group heading="Static Header, inner accordion" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
        This content is straight in the template.
      </uib-accordion-group>
      <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
        {{group.content}}
      </uib-accordion-group>
      <uib-accordion-group heading="Dynamic Header inner accordion 1t">
        <p>The body of the uib-accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
      </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>

  </uib-accordion-group>
  <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups1">
    {{group.content}}
  </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

[I have created a plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kpLtJqUutmm7hyWeKm5z?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both you accordions share a model in `is-open="status.isFirstOpen"` (line 41 & 44 in your plunk), that means when that value changes, both accordions will have their drawers opened and closed at the same time

Change the inner accordion's `is-open` to some other model value like `is-open="inner_status.isFirstOpen`.

And just to be sure, make sure all accordions use different values for their properties, that will keep them properly decoupled.

Comment: Can I use multiple controller for items with ng-repeat instead of `inner_status`? But idk what will be in `is-open` attribute, maybe something like `is-open='status["item_name"].open'`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what is it you wan to do. `inner_status` should be a boolean, and `ng-repeat` creates a scope for each iterated item

Comment: Open Accordion 2 and then any nested accordion. http://plnkr.co/edit/FTPKe9aBsvUWLMaSH5m2?p=preview

Comment: give them different values for `is-open` (as answered above), if the accordions are nested than the DOM objects assigned to them should also be nested.

Comment: and.. if I have lots of content in nested accordion, I open it and then I scroll down, open second nested accordion and it's automaticaly scrolls down to the same position. http://plnkr.co/edit/FTPKe9aBsvUWLMaSH5m2?p=preview Can I avoid this?

Comment: i think you should open a new question for this.